# How can i get HTML index based on HTML data i have using selenium python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I am very new in selenium, I want to click collapsed tab which contained by dynamic websites. I am using

```
//a[@href[contains(.,"Text")]]
```

for searching text in the page. suppose I getting 3 tag which contains this text. I am using

```
get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

and get HTML content and fetch class name using regex but when I send click event using javascript it clicks all tab which is under that class, so I want an index of that HTML tab which I found using text query. how can I get the index?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-8">
```

French Open 2019
   
   15:30ATP Dubai Center Court : Berankis vs Medvedev
   
   15:30ATP Dubai Court 1 : Gerasimov vs Haase
   
   15:30ATP Dubai Court 3 : Berrettini vs Kudla
   
   16:00Jacq vs Kolar
   
   17:00ATP Dubai Court 1 : Safwat vs Baghdatis
   
   17:00ATP Dubai Court 3 : Hurkacz vs Moutet
   
   17:30ATP Dubai Center Court : Nishikori vs Paire
   
   18:30ATP Dubai Court 1 : Berdych vs Ivashka
   
   19:00Pel / Sancic vs G. Granollers / Miedler
   
   19:00Eysseric / Hernandez vs Bonzi / Halys
   
   19:00ATP Sao Paulo Center Court : Sakamoto vs Munar
   
   19:00ATP Sao Paulo Court 1 : Marterer / Mies vs Marcondes / Matos
   
   20:00ATP Dubai Court 1 : Coric vs Kukushkin
   
   20:30W. Gonzalez / Voljacques vs Margaroli / Vavassori
   
   20:30ATP Dubai Center Court : Cilic vs Monfils
   
   20:30ATP Sao Paulo Center Court : Lorenzi vs Londero
   
   20:30ATP Sao Paulo Court 1 : Martinez vs Dellien
   
   21:00Safiullin vs Brown
   
   22:00Torpegaard vs M. Ymer
   
   22:00ATP Dubai Center Court : Ebden vs Tsitsipas
   
   22:00ATP Sao Paulo Center Court : Bagnis vs Ramos Vinolas
   
   22:00ATP Sao Paulo Court 1 : Jebavy / Molteni vs Carballes Baena / Jaziri
   
   23:00Barrere vs Serdarusic
   
   23:30Furness / Jacq vs Begemann / Junaid
   
   23:30ATP Sao Paulo Center Court : Bellucci / Dutra Silva vs L. Mayer / J. Sousa
   
   23:30ATP Sao Paulo Court 1 : Marrero / Oswald vs Delbonis / M. Gonzalez
   
   Feb 27th, 2019
   00:30Gombos vs Stakhovsky
   
   01:00ATP Sao Paulo Court 1 : P. Cuevas / Zeballos vs Demoliner / Nielsen
   
   02:00Choinski vs Pavlasek
   
   02:00ATP Sao Paulo Court 1 : Arneodo / Nys vs Arevalo / Cerretani
   
   03:00ATP Sao Paulo Center Court : Seyboth Wild vs E. Ymer
   
   04:30ATP Sao Paulo Center Court : Ruud vs T. Monteiro

Comment: Please shear the URL in order to find the index you are looking for...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the element which is exists more than once either you can use for loop or `Index`.As per your statement you are looking after index.Here you go.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//a[@href[contains(.,"Text")]])[0]') //where Index zero for 1st element.
```

In that way you can increase index value based on which element you would like to click.

Comment: @moshe Slavin:Thanks!I forgot to change the `string` ''

Comment: no, I don't want index from that 3 elements I want the index of DOM structure based on HTML data which I get using object.get_attribute('outerHTML'). Or any other way but I want index like that which element I searched and founded, I can click on that HTML element using selenium or javascript inside selenium.

Comment: Use for loop then Or If possible you could share html.

Comment: <a title="F1 Testing Barcelona 2019" href="/1-f1-testing-barcelona-2019-live-streaming" class="col-12 mb-1 text-left btn btn-secondary text-white collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#qwOmdh643591" onclick="return false"><span class="vleague formula-1 mr-2 align-bottom"></span><span content="2019-02-26T13:00" data-nsixlb="2019-02-26" class="EAxImK mr-2">18:30</span><span>F1 Testing Barcelona 2019</span></a>